# Unicode character order problem when text is displayed

Tags: text, unicode

I am working on an application that converts text into some other characters of the extended ASCII character set that gets displayed in custom font.

The program operation essentially parses the input string using regex, locates the standard characters and outputs them as converted before returning a string with the modified text which displays correctly when viewed with the correct font.

Every now and again, the function returns a string where the characters are displayed in the wrong order, almost like they are corrupted or some data is missing from the Unicode double width spacing. I have examined the binary output, the hex data, and inspected the data in the function before i return it and everything looks ok, but every once in a while something goes wrong and cant quite put my finger on it.

To see an example of what i mean when i say the order is weird, just take a look at the following piece of converted text output from the program and try to highlight it with your mouse. You will see that it doesn't highlight in the order you expect despite how it appears.

Has anyone seen anything like this before and have they any ideas as to what is going on?

ך┼♫יἯ╡П♪דἰ

Comment: You're mixing LTR and RTL text (either characters with that property or using marker characters). Also: for the love of all that's good, please forget the term "extended ASCII", it's way more vague than most users of the term realize and as such basically meaningless. Also: ASCII has **nothing** to do with what you're doing (other than being an ancient inspiration/base for Unicode).

Comment: Appreciate ascii as a description is pretty vague but there really wasnt many other tags to pick on SO that i could think of to describe this problem that would get me any reach. I will look into the LTR,RTL and see if that shines any light on the problem at hand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing various Unicode characters with different LTR/RTL characteristics.

LTR means "left-to-right" and is the direction that English (and many other western language) text is written.

RTL is "right-to-left" and is used mostly by Arabic and Hebrew (as well as [several other scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_script)).

By default when rendering Unicode text the engine will try to use the directionality of the characters to figure out what direction a given part of the code should go. And normally that works just fine because Hebrew words will have only Hebrew letters and English words will only use letters from the Latin alphabet, so for each chunk there's a easily guessable direction that makes sense.

But you are mixing letters from different scripts and with different directionality.

For example `ך` is U+05DA HEBREW LETTER FINAL KAF, but you also use two other Hebrew characters. You can use something like [this page](https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer#e=15rilLzimavXmeG8r-KVodCf4pmq15PhvLA) to list the Unicode characters you used.

You can either

1. not use "wrong" directionality letters or
2. make the direction explict using a [Left-to-right mark character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark).

**Edit:** Last but not least: I just realized that you said "custom font": if you expect displaying with a specific custom font, then you should really be using one of the [private use areas](http://custom%20use%20area) in Unicode: they are **explicitly** reserved for private use like this (i.e. where the characters *don't* match the publicly defined glyphs for the codepoints). That would also avoid surprises like the ones you get, where some of the used characters have different rendering properties.

Comment: Also worth noting that RTL characters have the property `unicodedata.bidirectional(c) == 'R'` if you want to avoid them.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for the prompt response and detailed information. The issue was exactly like you said @Joachim Sauer. Once that was established we migrated the troublesome characters away from the RTL text area of unicode and all was working well again. I dont seem to be able to mark this question as closed or completed so i have marked the first answer as accepted. Cheers.

Comment: @SyntaxisTaxsyn: Glas I could help. There's no "marked this as completed", there's only "closed" (which is not used for completed, but if a question doesn't fit the rules for some reason). Simply accepting the answer that helped you the most (and upvoting any that you found useful) is perfectly acceptable, you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Ok thanks. Whilst i have used SO extensively over the years (almost every question I have ever had has been asked here before : )), I’m fairly new to the process of asking questions and contributing. This is a great resource here with a fantastic community and I am keen to add value in any way I can to say thanks for the advice I have received here over the years.